# SQL LOAD XML: Как убрать не нужные поля

Tags: sql, xml

есть xml файлы, которые заливаются в БД через foreach и переменную

```
                LOAD XML
                LOCAL INFILE '..../files/$xml' IGNORE
                INTO TABLE db.items_set CHARACTER SET UTF8
                ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<offer>'
```

Необходимое мне ***поле*** из этих файлов называется `<name>`, но в некоторых xml есть поля с ***атрибутами*** c тем же названием `<param name="">`

Пример файла

```
<offer>
    <delivery>true</delivery>
      <ordering>На складе</ordering>
    <name>ModNation Racers</name>
    <param name="Альтернативное название">Игра обещает стать новой LittleBigPlanet!</param>
  </offer>
```

Проблема в том что sql автоматом берет значение из атрибута. Я не могу найти решение как сделать выбор именно поля name. Если есть предложения, как просто зачистить XML файл, то это тоже решение моей проблемы.

СТРУКТУРА ТАБЛИЦЫ

```
CREATE TABLE `items_set`
                (
                    `item_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    `short_url` CHAR  NULL,
                    `id` INT,
                    `url` TEXT( 255 ) NOT NULL,
                    `price` INT NOT NULL,
                    `currencyId` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
                    `picture` TEXT NULL,
                    `name` TEXT NULL,
                    `model` TEXT NULL,
                    `description` TEXT NULL
                )
```

ЧАСТЬ ФАЙЛА XML

```
<offer id="5395807" available="true" group_id="5395807">
    <url>detail/id/5395807/?from=prt_xml_facet</url>
    <price>1190</price>
    <baseprice>1190</baseprice>
    <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>
    <categoryId>1143736</categoryId>
    <categoryId>1143749</categoryId>
    <picture>multimedia/audio_cd_covers/1001854135.jpg</picture>
    <delivery>true</delivery>
    <orderingTime>
      <ordering>На складе</ordering>
    </orderingTime>
    <name>Kane &amp; Lynch 2: Dog Days</name>
    <vendor>Square Enix, / IO Interactive</vendor>
    <description> Сделка сорвалась, и теперь у подельников есть двое суток, чтобы разобраться с ситуацией и наказать всех виновных. Криминальная драма с участием шанхайской...</description>
    <age>18+</age>
    <barcode>5021290042704</barcode>
    <param name="Альтернативное название">Платформа</param>
    <param name="Издание">Коллекционное</param>
    <param name="Год выпуска">2010</param>
  </offer>
```

ЗАПРОС SQL

```
           $sql = "
                LOAD XML
                LOCAL INFILE 'files/$xml' IGNORE
                INTO TABLE aggregator.items_set CHARACTER SET UTF8
                ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<offer>'
            ";
            mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

[image: Выполнение запроса]

Comment: Непонятно... добавьте в вопрос: 1) целевую структуру (CREATE TABLE) 2) корректно загружаемую запись в пример файла 3) результаты загрузки в таблицу для этих 2 записей в примере файла: текущий и желаемый.

Comment: PS. Сейчас из примера файла грузятся данные в 4 поля, с именами `delivery`, `ordering`, `name` и `\`Альтернативное название\``.

Comment: *предложения, как просто зачистить XML файл* Укажите точно, от чего зачистить (или полный список того, что оставить). Хотя по этому вопросу лучше создать новую тему - где определиться ещё и с языком программирования.

Comment: @Akina Изменил, в поле name как видите берется атрибут но не поле

Comment: К сожалению, не вижу именно той записи, которая показана как "ЧАСТЬ ФАЙЛА XML". Соответственно непонятно, откуда берутся значения, попавшие в поле `name`. Попробуйте в качестве эксперимента тупо (да хоть в блокноте) заменить `<param` на `<field`.

Comment: @Akina через текстовый редактор удалил все записи <param и все заработало как надо, есть ли способ как сделать тоже самое но посредству php или sql? Делать через foreach  будет не самым лучшим вариантом так как значений более 10 тыс.

Comment: Если структура файла строгая (сначала идут все статические параметры именно в таком количестве и порядке) - можно попробовать использовать позиционную SET-форму загрузки и dummy-переменные. Если же структура "плавает" - то только удалять все теги `param`.